# Select 2 value from the same column

Tags: sql-server

i need to select bid-id that has status ='expired' and another one that has status ='unsold' can someone help please?

```
SELECT *,
       SelectBidID, DATENAME(mm, Date) AS Month
FROM   BID
WHERE  (Status = 'Won')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT  *, SelectBidID, DATENAME(mm, Date) AS Month,
        Case [Status]
            When 'expired' Then 'sucessfull'
            When 'unsold' Then 'unsucessfull'
            --Else 'Unknown'
        End As [Status]
FROM    BID
WHERE   [Status] = 'expired'
        OR [Status] = 'unsold'
```

Comment: i need to have the two value separately such as all expired and all unsold, i will put this in chart

Comment: pls. make your question have more details and concise.

Comment: what do you mean separate, cause you can already separate them by status?

Comment: yes but as if i need to select bidid where status = 'expired' as sucessfull bid and select bidid where status='unsold' unsucessfull u see what i mean?

Comment: Pls. see updates above, I hoped that is want you mean.

Comment: Sorry missed the comma, see it again

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Unsold AS
       (SELECT *,
           Select BidID, DATENAME(mm, Date) AS Month
            ,Status As U_Status
    FROM   BID
    WHERE  (Status = 'unsold')
    ),Expired AS
       (SELECT *,
           SelectBidID, DATENAME(mm, Date) AS Month
            ,Status as E_Status
    FROM   BID
    WHERE  (Status = 'expired')
    )


    Select s.*, s.U_Status, e.E_Status from Unsold s 
    INNER JOIN Expired e ON s.SelectBidID =e.SelectBidID
```